# Odoo installation Magento Connector

Tags: magento-1.9, database, backend

I am new to Odoo/OpenERP. I am trying to install odoo and odoo-magento-connector in ubuntu 14.04 using this tutorial http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2014/09/how-to-install-openerp-odoo-8-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/
I am getting stuck in Step 6, /opt/odoo/openerp-server after typing this command i get error shown in the below snap shot
[image]